# Why is stack memory "cheaper" than heap memory in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Compare the following two:

```
int arr[10]; // stack memory
int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)*10); // heap memory
```

Both are essentially allocating 10 integer variables. However, we often say that the first one is much cheaper (faster to alloc and dealloc) b/c it simply moves ahead the stack pointer.

We know that all programs run in virtual memory space, and only the portion that a program actually uses will be allocated (aka mapped to physical memory), and unused ones stay virtual. And that's how the OS shares physical memory between different programs.

So here comes my question. It seems to me that no matter how you allocate the memory (on stack or on heap), one thing in common is that the OS needs to find & reserve a physical memory block, and map the virtual memory address, whether its on stack or on heap, to the physical address. The same for deallocation, when the system needs to remove the mapping & free the physical memory. Then why is stack allocation/deallocation faster? The biggest overhead in memory allocation seems pretty fair between the two.

Comment: You completely misestimate the cost of finding space with heap allocation.  Go study the implementation in K&R 2nd Edn, or look at the options in Knuth.  The heap has to track how space over longer durations than a single function execution — but the stack memory simply uses the space in a LIFO way (stack).  See also the non-portable `alloca()`.

Answer (score 13):

Calls to `malloc` and `free` typically require somewhere between a few 100's and a few 1,000's of instructions on average depending on implementation, current fragmentation of the heap, and other details.

Allocating and deallocating the stack frame for a function requires on the order of 4 instructions.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `malloc` has a lot more instructions involved, which is in C library, and in some cases it also involves doing system calls into the kernel to get new memory space allocated.

Answer (score 5):

The `int a[10]` on stack is basically free. On x86 (be that 16, 32 or 64-bit mode) on function prologue, the current stack pointer is copied to base pointer; then the stack pointer is adjusted downwards (by `SUB`tract opcode) downwards so that there is enough space between the base pointer and stack pointer to store *all* the local variables in that function frame.

As local variables are not initialized in C, defining

```
int a[10];
```

might not have any less overhead than

```
int a[432], b[234], c[234], d[123], e[123], f[34], g[23];
```

e.g. for the first the compiler could write a prologue that caused the stack pointer be subtracted by 16 bytes, and for the second by 1216 bytes.

Then on function exit, as the compiler had stored the old stack pointer to the base pointer register, the base pointer register contents are stored to the stack pointer register again, and no other clean-up is required.

---

Now, for `malloc` things are trickier. If the program is multi-threaded, there needs to be either an arena/pool for each thread or there must be some kind of exclusion to lock out the other threads. `malloc` needs to find a block that is big enough, then update its bookkeeping. Then `free` must do the same steps as well - locking the mutual exclusion device and updating the bookkeeping.

---

All in all a single `malloc`/`free` pair has at least tens of instructions of overhead, whereas stack variables are in principle free.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you measure cost, actually.

With modern operating systems, a program's stack is typically allocated and assigned to the process during program startup (with some exceptions if a process' quota is changed while it is running).  From there, operations by the program that use the stack (e.g. calling a function, assigning `auto` variables, etc) are pretty quick (as far as the program is concerned, the stack is in a fixed location).  In comparison, heap is not allocated for the program until requested so the program must explicitly request an allocation from the operating system when needed.    For this reason, as far as the program is concerned, stack is inexpensive in comparison with heap - no need to request it from the operating system, no need to wait for the operating system to respond, the program uses stack sequentially (i.e.  if function `A()` calls `B()`, then the stack usage is orderly) etc etc.    The only exceptions come if the program attempts to use more stack than is available, but that consideration affects heap as well.

From the perspective of the modern operating system, there is often actually no difference whatsoever between heap and stack as seen by a running program.   All the heap and stack for processes are physically drawn from the same resource (consisting of RAM, swap, etc) and the operating system needs to manage allocation and deallocation of all of it for all processes, using similar data structures, etc.    There is therefore little difference, as far as the operating system, in allocating stack or heap to a program - the only difference is that stack is requested once when a program starts and released once as a program exits, while heap is (for a lot of programs) requested and released many times while the program is subsequently running.   But the cost to the operating system is based on number and order of requests for memory and returns of that memory for release, not on whether the requests are categorised as heap or stack by the requesting processes.

Some programming techniques involve the program statically allocating all the heap it needs during startup - after which no heap is ever requested again by the program.   From the perspective of an operating system, the requests for heap by such a program are not much different to requests for stack - they all come out of the same memory resource as far as the operating system is concerned.

Older operating systems and hardware did often manage heap and stack completely differently.   Physically, there was often a distinction, as heap and stack resided in different memory chips with different performance characteristic - and, in practice, the "stack" was a fast but small amount of memory, while heap was a slower but larger amount of memory.   Logically, since heap was more abundant than stack (and requests to it were ad-hoc) there was also more work for the system to keep track of available heap, and more potential for other costs (e.g. memory fragmentation) that increased the net cost of heap over stack.

Answer (score 2):

When a program enters a function, a new stack frame is created. When a variable is allocated on the stack, it is pushed into the current stack frame. When a function is exited the stack frame is deallocated. This static knowledge of when to create and destroy data makes it easy for the cpu to optimize the stack.

The heap on the other hand is more dynamic. It is a big chunk of memory (rather than many small, linear frames) that is managed by the developer using malloc and free. There is no real way to optimize such memory.

This difference is made more prominent by the fact that heap allocations are referenced using pointers rather than directly. Each access to the heap requires a dereference operation before hand. Each access on the stack is memory local and easily cached in the cpu.

The details of all the above are too many and too complex to cover here but, this should give a basic overview for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Because stack space for program is pre-allocated and no system call involved.

Heap space allocation needs system call, which involves a chain of operations to the kernel and thus slower.

But it should be neglectable if you don't do it like a billion times

Comment: But the system won't know how much stack space will be used throughout a program's lifetime, correct? That would mean that if a program is big, when it's stack outgrows what's pre-allocated, the stack allocation will become as expensive as heap allocation?

Comment: @onezero you are right the system doesn't know. If the program tries to access too much stack space, it will cause stack overflow (which this websites name comes from), and the program will crash, or even worse

Comment: @OneZero No, but it usually doesn't matter as the compiler figures out the size of objects, and all it takes to allocate/deallocate stack space for a function call is incrementing/decrementing a pointer. That's like pennies compared to asking the kernel to search for available memory, and plan where to allocate it

Comment: @alexyan No the compiler wouldn't know in case like recursive call, C style variable length array, or if you do alloca

Comment: @texasbruce sorry I meant it knows how much to allocate for a single run of the mill function call, and that it doesn't matter if you don't know how much stack to allocate throughout a program's lifetime. The stack is still contiguous, so allocations and deallocations won't require anything more than moving a pointer, which is generally much cheaper than heap allocations

Comment: @texasbruce This is not right. Heap memory is managed by the C library, which runs in user space. No C library of the dozen or so I've studied invokes a kernel call billions of times.

Comment: @gene Heap allocation such as alloc will call C runtime library (libstd in Linux), and the library will invoke system call from there.

Comment: @texasbruce Yes. They call `sbrk` or `brk` or equivalent, but never billions of times.

Comment: @gene I didn't say it calls sbrk or brk a billion times... I said the overhead of doing alloc is neglectable if he doesn't do alloc a billion times